# Iterate through array passed from controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I'm using Ruby on Rails.

Here is my code for the view, where I make a post to the controller, passing parameter "tplangroup.id":

```
             <div id="collapse">
                 <%= form_tag(tplans_collapse_tplans_path, :method => 'post', :remote => true ) do %>
                    <%= hidden_field_tag(:tplangroup_id, tplangroup.id) %>
                 <% end %>
              </div>
```

Here is my code on the controller end, where it parses the necessary data and shoots back array  "@ordered_tplans"

```
             def collapse_tplans
               @collapsed_tplangroup = Tplangroup.find(params[:tplangroup_id])
               tplans_from_tplangroup = @collapsed_tplangroup.tplans
               @ordered_tplans = tplans_from_tplangroup.order("favrank DESC")

               return @ordered_tplans
              end
```

Since I called :remote => true in the original form located in the view, it passes this array to a file called "collapse_tplans.js"

My question is: what is the best way/practice to parse through this array now passed to the js file, and display its contents in the view?  Do I use rails code in the js file to manipulate the object?  Or do I do it all in javascript/jquery?  What is the best practice, and could you provide any example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really kind of depends on how you want to go about it, as with all code, there are many ways to skin a cat.  I find the easiest way is to use the return ujs as an erb file (`collapse_tplans.js.erb`) and from there, choose the element on the page you want to attach the retuned object to, and call a standard erb or haml partial where your iterations can be done clearly.

e.g.

In `collapse_tplans.js.erb`

```
$('#my_wacky_element').append("<%= j render(:partial => 'collapse_tplans', :locals => { :ordered_tplans => @ordered_tplans }) %>");
```

Then in
`_collapse_tplans.html.erb`

```
<ul>
  <%= ordered_tplans.each do |tplan| %>
    <li><%= tplan.attribute %></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a RailsCast on how to pass data to js from rails:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?view=asciicast